# Rails 4 ActiveRecord throws PG::UnableToSend on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ubuntu, activerecord

We have a `Ruby v.2.0.0-p247` on `Rails v4.0.1` application using `pg gem v0.17.0`.

The application runs smoothly under `Mac OS X Mavericks v10.9` with `PostgreSQL Server v9.2.4` installed using `HomeBrew` but it throws the following exception under `Ubuntu v13.04` using `PostgreSQL Server 9.1`:

`PG::UnableToSend: server closed the connection unexpectedly`

`This probably means the server terminated abnormally before or while processing the request.`

The exception occurs after transactional queries (form submission).

I tried the following with `database.yml`:

1. Adding `reconnect: true`
2. Adding `port: 5432`
3. Adding `socket: /var/run/postgresq/SOCKET_FILE`

And tried the following with PostgreSQL configuration under Ubuntu:

1. Disabling SSL.
2. Changing TCP keepalives parameters to pump timeout.
3. Changing log level to `DEBUG` and search for possible errors on PostgreSQL Server.

Also tried:

1. Downgrade to pg gem v0.16.0.
2. Update all Ubuntu 13.04 packages to latest versions.

What could possible be wrong?

UPDATES:

12/03/2013: Some suggested checking firewall settings. `ufw status` said that `ufw` is disabled. 
12/08/2013: After trying out with a vanilla Rails app and a lot of mangling with the current application, the problem is originating from `rails4/activerecord-session_store` gem. Line 47 in `lib/active_record/session_store/session.rb` is the culprit.

Comment: Could you login through the console? the One of the probable reason is that your PG installation is not clean. There might be version conflicts.

Comment: @ArihantGodha not sure what you mean by login through the console but Rails console starts just fine.

Comment: @owahab have you specified the port of your PG database in database.yml?

Comment: @SamD yes, and that didn't help.

Comment: @owahab You're using `socket` config to set the socket file. AR Postgres adapter doesn't accept a `socket` config, perhaps you mean `host` config instead. Also, `host` takes only the the directory of the socket file then it adds the socket file name afterwards. Maybe this is the issue.

Comment: @AhmadSherif I actually removed the socket after few trials, my last version doesn't use socket to connect to the server.

Comment: Was the vanilla app successful?

Comment: Yes, as I pointed in the original question, I am now sure it's activerecord-session_store gem that was causing the problem. Yet I have no idea why.

Comment: Line 47 of which file? in `activerecord-session_store`?

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure that activerecord-session_store really is the culprit; it might just be that saving the session is the first query that happens, so this is where the issue pops up. Can you clean Postgres' log, enable DEBUG level, restart the server, produce the error through Rails and show us the complete log output between server start and error?

Comment: @NickUrban updated the original question, sorry :)

Comment: @janfoeh even if I told you switching the session from database to cookies fixed my problem?

Comment: Are you able to connect to Postgres using `psql` and execute the queries in that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This basically happens when you use an old version of [launchy](http://rubygems.org/gems/launchy) , and as per this [issue](https://github.com/copiousfreetime/launchy/pull/77) on launchy's git repo quoting @infertux

> In the rare case when `exec` fails to run the command - typically when the file cannot be opened raising `Errno::ENOENT` - Launchy would raise an exception but not showing any output

You can check your `Gemfile.lock` to see if you're using a version of `launchy` below 2.4.1, and I doubt that you're using `letter_opener` Gem in your development environment which depends on `launchy` so updating `letter_opener` to 1.2.0 will update `launchy` to a version above 2.4.0 mostly 2.4.2 which has this issue fixed

All credit goes to @infertux

Comment: FYI, all current versions of `letter_opener` (including v1.2.0) only depend on `launchy` v2.2.
https://github.com/ryanb/letter_opener/blob/v1.2.0/letter_opener.gemspec

Answer (score 1):

It would really help if you provided your database.yml file

The default connection method is a unix domain socket, not to be confused with a TCP/IP socket. The unix domain socket connection method is used by default.

You should check that the unix user that you are trying to run rails under has sufficient permissions to access the domain socket (typically at `/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432`)

Try typing the following as your rails user:

```
psql
```

If you get a database connection error then its likely a permissions problem if postgres is actually running.

You can check your `/etc/postgresql.conf` file and have postgres configure the group and permissions on the socket when it starts:

```
unix_socket_directory = '/var/run/postgresql'       # dont worry if yours is different
#unix_socket_group = ''                             # default is usually ok
#unix_socket_permissions = 0777                     # uncomment this if needed
```

Another option is to add the user to the group that has write access to the socket, vs allowing all users on the machine access with the 0777 permissions setting above.  You may want to create a `postres_users` group for this purpose if the default Ubuntu groups provide insufficient granularity for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like there's confusion about the connection method. PostgreSQL supports the two methods:

1. Socket
2. TCP/IP

These are completely, utterly different. :-)

In your question, you show a `socket` setting, but mention TCP. I suggest to focus on each of these two ways of connecting in isolation and see which produces results. I.e., create two version branches `pg-socket` and `pg-tcpip` just to make things clear. Then, clean up your config file and attempt to connect via both methods.

Often, a socket connection is easier because you just need to know the pathname of the socket "file". No fireware settings are necessary (because no TCP/IP networking is involved.)

Update your question after doing this and tell us how each of the two methods did for you.

Comment: Please paste in your database config entries for `development`. Also, please try creating a Rails app from scratch, and see if it connects: `rails new testapp --database=postgresql`

Answer (score 0):

Have you set `keepalives` as specified here http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS similar issue was solved with it at: https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/issue/170/pg-unabletosend-connection-timed-out

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried settings the `keepalives` but they didn't fix my problem.

Comment: @owahab you might as well submit an issue at https://bitbucket.org/ged/ruby-pg/issues/new